# Regular expression: Postgres SQL query is returning all records available in the table

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

The below Postgres SQL query is returning all records available in the table.
Can someone give explanation for this? . 
Also please let me know what * represents in case of postgres regular expression.

```
Employee table contains :

name
Chennai
Delhi
Hydrabad
NewYark
ABC

select * from employee where name ~ 'Z*'
```

Comment: The star after the Z means 0 or more Z (somewhere in the string). So the regex engine chooses 0 Z and it matches every string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` quantifier means **zero or more**. Since every name contains at least zero `Z` characters, every row is returned.

You don't need to use a regex to find strings starting with a character, you can just use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE name LIKE 'Z%';
```

If you want names starting with Z **using a regex**, try this:

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE name ~ '^Z';
```

If you want names containing at least one Z, try one of these:

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE name LIKE '%Z%';
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE name ~ 'Z';
```

Comment: @araqnid: Picture me slapping my forehead. It's funny how easy it is to overthink a regex. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct query for finding name starting with 'Z' :

```
SELECT record FROM myrecords WHERE name ~ '^Z';
```

in  your query :

```
select * from employee where name ~ 'Z*'
```

the meaning is where the name matches ZERO or MORE sequences of character "Z", hence returning all records.

- `*` in the matching criteria means ZERO or MORE occurences.
- `*` along with tilda means case insensitive match i.e. ~* 'Z' will match both "z" and "Z"

For more have a look here :

http://oreilly.com/pub/a/databases/2006/02/02/postgresq_regexes.html?page=1

Comment: Just to make the example complete: To get all rows where name starts with Z no regex is necessary. `where name like 'Z%'` would do the same thing